# Order grouped table by id user sql

Tags: sql, group-by

I want to order a grouped statement using as reference the number choosen by an specific user.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM likes 
 WHERE /**/
 GROUP BY type
```

TABLE

```
id_user  type
1420    1   
1421    3
1422    3
1424    7
1425    4
1426    2
1427    1
```

expected result (at the end what user 1425 choosed)

```
1
2
3
7
4 //choosen by id_user 1425
```

I want to put the last row with the number choosed by the user. i just cant figure that out

Comment: group by type order by id desc.

Comment: And, what does your best attempt at resolving this look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate and use a conditional `max` for ordering, like so:

```
select type
from likes
group by likes
order by max(case when id_user = 1425 then 1 else 0 end), type
```

If any row for the given `type` has an `id_user` that matches the chosen value, the conditional `max` returns `1`, wich puts it last in the resultset. The second ordering criteria break the ties for groups that do not fulfill the condition.

If you are running MySQL, you can simplify the `order by` clause a little:

```
order by max(id_user = 1425), type
```

Comment: wow. Im using pdo, it worked with  `order by max(id_user = 1425),id` what would be the difference between using `id_user` or `type at the end`? thank you.

Comment: @max: you just can't use `id_user` in the `order by` clause, because it is not part of the `group by` clause.